# Ways of finding a value within an array where you never know the end of the array (and there fore the length)?

Tags: arrays, inverted-index, large-data

Just got back from a technical interview and one of the first questions that stumped me went something like this:

"Find a value within an array (the interviewer specified that it was within an inverted index) with millions of elements in it. You do not know where the end of the array is, since we are constantly adding elements, and therefore you cannot know the length."

I gave the interviewer the naive solution of iterating through every element, and then couldn't think of anything beyond that since something like a binary search needs to know the end of the array.

Is there an algorithm that would allow me to find a target element without knowing the end of the array?

Comment: What's your question? This is overly broad as it stands.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Well, if "we are constantly adding elements" there are two parts: a) the already existing elements b) the new one. You can sort the existing part and insert the new one in its sorted place. You can search in the already sorted part and also compare with the new element.